# Why dont application objects support open extensions?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

One part of the docs says you should migrate your schemaExtensions to the new format. But then the Application object doesnt support. Why would you leave that one out?

So, I'm looking at this documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/opentypeextension-post-opentypeextension?view=graph-rest-1.0

It seems very odd that the application resource was left off of this list. The old-style extensions were there for application objects, per this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-list-extensionproperty?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http, but we are told here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/extensionproperty?view=graph-rest-1.0 that this is for backwards compatibility only.

Adding custom properties to applications is super useful, to link them to cmdb, portfolios, source code repositories, azure RG where they are deployed, etc.

Just trying to understand why they cannot be extended.

Comment: Please let us know which document and context you are referring to?

Comment: see modified description